# How to present waterfall look with UICollectionView and data model fetched from internet

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am fetching data which contains things like text string, picture url from internet and I have converted them into my data model.

Now I want to present the data with `UICollectionView` in two equal columns and rows with different heights.

Since the picture downloaded could be in different sizes, each `UICollectionViewCell` should have different sizes. But I am making them fixed width so the height would adapt to the width dynamically.

What I did was that I created a custom `UICollectionView`, a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and a default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, I pass a pointer to the data model array to my custom `UICollectionViewCell`, and assign values from data model to the sub views in the cell in `layoutSubViews`.

The issue is that I cannot calculate the `height` for each cell since my data model has only the `url` and the `size` of the images can be known only after they are downloaded.

Now what I have done is only wait until the images are downloaded, then I get the height of the images and add it to my data model. BUT this should be WRONG since when I run it the cells are messed up like this:

[image]

So my question is how I can re-layout each cell (when is the best time to do that) once I get the height of the images OR if there is better solution to the whole thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and I found it can be complex to custom your own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to present cells with dynamic height that would cross the row boundaries.

I found a good lib called `CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout` which helps me out.

[Here](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) is the link to author's github if anyone is interested.

Comment: CHTCollectionviewwallerfalllayout not helped.same issue with me..do you have demo.@Boris